# Switch case on Strings is not compatible with Smart-GWT

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt, smartgwt

We are using smart-gwt for our application along with Java. The switch case on strings have been introduced in Java 1.7, and used to
work in GWT 2.5.

I have upgraded my GWT version to 2.7 and Java to 1.7 but the switch case on strings is not working.

With GWT 2.5, it  was showing compile errors in Eclipse but after GWT upgrade, it is not showing any such errors but it is getting runtime exceptions.

I think it is a problem with Smart GWT version, we are using smart-gwt 4.1.

Could any body tell me is my assumption is correct?

Comment: Can you add the stack trace from one or two of those runtime errors (if they are distinct from one another) to your question?

Answer (score 0):

SmartClient and Smart GWT packages only require a JDK (version 1.5 or later).

From [SmartGWT download page](https://www.smartclient.com/product/downloadOtherReleases.jsp)

Works fine on my projects.

Answer (score 0):

GWT 2.7 unexpectedly dropped support for `<script>` tags in .gwt.xml files (a longstanding feature used by many projects).

We had to re-implement this feature within SmartGWT in order to be compatible with GWT 2.7.  This was done about a week ago, so you just need to download a more recent patched build of 4.1:

```
http://smartclient.com/builds
```

Comment: yes it won't support tags in .gwt.xml files, but what is the relation between my question and the above answer.

Comment: I typed that they dropped support for <script> tags, the forum mangled it.  The absence of support for <script> tags will lead to immediate runtime errors if you try to use GWT 2.7 with SmartGWT builds older than around Feb 10.